# Как добавлять через .append только определённое количество блоков

Tags: javascript, img, append

Добавляю в блок картинки:

```js
$('#test').append('<img class="IMG show" src="' + word_array[randomNum] + '"style="left:'+ clickX +'px; top:'+ clickY +'px; transform: scale('+ scale +',' + scale +') rotate('+ rotate +'deg);">');
```

Как сделать, чтоб при добавлении больше десяти, например, 11-ой первая удалялась?

Comment: Технически можете перед выполнением этого кода проверять, сколько на данный момент картинок уже есть, и если десять, то удалять первую

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $('#test').append('<img class="IMG show" src="' + word_array[randomNum] + '"style="left:'+ clickX +'px; top:'+ clickY +'px; transform: scale('+ scale +',' + scale +') rotate('+ rotate +'deg);">'); 

 var length = $('#test img').length;

  if(length >=10) {
        $('#test img').first().remove();
  }
```

Comment: Спасибо! работает )

Answer (score 2):

> Как сделать, чтоб при добавлении больше десяти, например, 11-ой первая удалялась?

Первая удаляется, к концу добавляется новая рандомная фотка.

Вот пример:

```js
var word_array = ['//picsum.photos/100/120', '//picsum.photos/100/101', '//picsum.photos/100/132', '//picsum.photos/100/143', '//picsum.photos/100/154'];
var randomNum;


$('.add').on('click', function() {
  randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * word_array.length));
  var img = $('img'); // Массив элементов img
  if (img.length >= 10) {
    // Удаляет первый элемент img
    img[0].remove();
  }
  $('#test').append('<img class="IMG show" src="' + word_array[randomNum] + '" ">');
})
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add">Add img</button>
<hr>
<div id="test"></div>
```